# Django template fetching value from option tag

Tags: python, django

I want to fetch selected option value, and then display content dependent of chosen option

template

```
<div class="match-wrapper">    
  <select name="team">
    {%for team in teams%}            
       <option class='option-select' value="{{team}}">{{team}}</option>
    {%endfor%}
  </select>
  {%for player in players%}
    <div data-team="AGO K1CK DV1 PIRATESPORTS IHG DC PRIDE AVEZ">
        <span>{{player}}</span>
    </div>
  {%endfor%}
</div>
```

views.py

```
def profile(request):
    players = {'AGO':['Szygenda', 'Zanzarah', 'Czekolad', 'Woolite', 'Mystqiues'], 'K1CK':['Ibo', 'Shlatan', 'Matislaw', 'Puki Style', 'Raxxo'],
        'DV1':['Sinmivak', 'Bruness', 'Czajek', 'Bullet', 'Pyrka'], 'Piratesports':['Konvektiv', 'Behave', 'Roison', 'Defles', 'Sedrion'],
        'IHG':['Melonik', 'Kikis', 'Niq', 'Unforgiven', 'Jesiz'], 'Pride':['Rifty', 'Raxhy', 'Warszi', 'KMŚ'], 'DC':['Unknown', 'Crazy', 'Fresskowy', 'Itrzrenifer', 'Blue45ty'],'Avez':['Czaru', 'Bolszak', 'Bucu', 'Trenie','Kubyd']
    }
    teams = ['AGO', 'K1CK', 'DV1', 'PIRATESPORTS', 'IHG', 'DC', 'PRIDE', 'AVEZ']

    context = {
        'teams':teams,
        'players':players['AGO'],

    }
    return render(request, 'profilecontent/profile.html', context)
```

Comment: Where does ago_players come from?, and in the iterations should be only {{team}}

Comment: ok i updated post, but still dont know how can i get value from option tag

Comment: You can either load the content you want to display dynamically with an ajax request or you can prefill the html page with the values and then use javascript to display the values for example. `{% if option.value %}` - option would be a template variable you prefill on the server side in this example.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to change what content is shown `if` condition, based on the selected option in the `for` loop? That isn’t something you can do just with Django templates, you need to either either use a form to submit the value of the `<select>`, or use JavaScript.

For the form approach you could follow the Django [Working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/) guide, it gives a good overview of how it all works. This approach will also allow you to use the data in other ways too, e.g. saving the chosen option for future visits.

The JavaScript approach can be good if you don’t want to reload the page before seeing changes. Here’s a simple example of how it could work.

```html
<div class="match-wrapper">
  <select name="team">
    {% for team in teams %}
      <option class="option-select" value="{{ team }}">{{ team }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>

  <div data-team="AGO">
    <span>AGO</span>
  </div>
  <div data-team="K1CK DV1 PIRATESPORTS IHG DC PRIDE AVEZ">
    <span>Not AGO</span>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  const select = document.querySelector('select[name="team"]');

  select.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
    const targets = document.querySelectorAll('[data-team]');
    for (const target of targets) {
      const teams = target.dataset.team.split(' ');
      target.hidden = !teams.includes(select.value);
    }
  });

  select.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
</script>
```

Comment: I think I wrong described my problem, and didn't provide all the data because I thought it won't be necessary. So I want to display players from dictionary dependent of chosen value in box. Updated Code.